# Please provide some FTP connection logs for a ProFTPD server

Tags: logging, ftp

I'm the author of an [FTP library](https://github.com/hgupta9/FluentFTP/) and I need to detect the [ProFTPD server](https://github.com/hgupta9/FluentFTP/issues/88#issuecomment-304430823) from the FTP messages it sends when you first connect to it. I need someone to provide a log from their favorite FTP program when they connect to a ProFTPD server, as I don't have access to one.

For example when I connect to a Pure-FTPd server, these are the logs I get:

```
[12:58:44] 220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
[12:58:44] 220-You are user number 2 of 150 allowed.
[12:58:44] 220-Local time is now 01:32. Server port: 21.
[12:58:44] 220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
[12:58:44] 220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
[12:58:44] USER ***
[12:58:44] 331 User *** OK. Password required
[12:58:44] PASS ****
```

So I will be able to detect the server using the line "Welcome to Pure-FTPd". There is no other way to detect this, even sending a SYST command only provides "Unix".

Comment: If developing a library, shouldn't you have test servers for this?

Answer (score 2):

The message is a configuration option...

http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_ServerIdent.html

> **`ServerIdent`** [ ServerIdent off|on [identification string]]
>
> Default
>   **`ServerIdent` on** *"ProFTPD [version] Server (server name) [hostname]"*